# TCPSocket connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby, ssl, tcp, websocket, betfair

```
require 'socket'
socket = TCPSocket.open('stream-api.betfair.com', '443') 
while line = socket.gets
  puts line.chop
end
socket.close
```

[I should receive](https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Exchange+Stream+API#ExchangeStreamAPI-Connection/ConnectionMessage) something like `{"op":"connection","connectionId":"002-230915140112-174"}`

but I receive `Connection reset by peer` which

> means the remote end would have sent a reset packet (RST) to kill the connection without an orderly shutdown (close). In that case you know it was the peer(client).

betfair included [a nodejs example](https://github.com/betfair/stream-api-sample-code/blob/master/node.js/app.js) and also [csharp/java examples](https://github.com/betfair/stream-api-sample-code)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, you should replace the string '443' by an integer :

```
TCPSocket.open('stream-api.betfair.com', 443)
```

Anyway, it seems to be related with the SSL negociation : the following Stackoverflow post gives a quick idea about what would work : [How to establish a SSL enabled TCP/IP Connection in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836847/how-to-establish-a-ssl-enabled-tcp-ip-connection-in-ruby). Using this method, I works.

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'

host = 'stream-api.betfair.com'
port = 443

socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)
ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new()
ssl_context.ssl_version = :SSLv23
ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, ssl_context)
ssl_socket.sync_close = true
ssl_socket.connect
while line = ssl_socket.gets
  p line
end
ssl_socket.close
```

Result :

```
"{\"op\":\"connection\",\"connectionId\":\"001-151118094105-259478\"}\r\n"
```

Dealing with SSL/TLS protected connection is sometime quite verbose with Ruby. In the example you gave, in NodeJS, the hint is the first line :

```
var tls = require('tls');
```